# Cast object to method generic type

Tags: c#, generics

This generates an error saying I cannot convert type *`ClassType`*
 to `T`. Is there any workaround for this?

Is there any way to specify that the type of `this` *can* in fact be converted to `T`?

```
public void WorkWith<T>(Action<T> method)
{
    method.Invoke((T)this);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

Not type-safe:

```
public void WorkWith<T>(Action<T> method)
{
    method.Invoke((T)(object)this);
}
```

This isn't typesafe because you can pass it any method that has a single parameter and no return value, like:

```
WorkWith((string x) => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

The typesafe "version" (using generic constraints):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void WorkWith<T>(Action<T> method) where T : MyClass
    {
        method.Invoke((T)this);
    }
}
```

The point here is that to be able to cast `this` to `T`, the compiler wants to be sure that `this` is always castable to `T` (so the need for the constraint). As shown in the not-type-safe example, the "classical" (unsafe) solution used with generics is passing through a cast to `object`.

Comment: Even though the user below may have had the wrong answer, it was ambiguous so I edited it and accepted. This answer is also very good because it was not ambiguous and shows the result in context with an explanation. I would like to accept both but oh well.

Comment: upvoted and deserves to be accepted answer compared to an answer which was originally wrong and contains no explanation...

Comment: @Selman22 I feel bad for the original poster but I have to agree. Changed.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void WorkWith<T>(Action<T> method) where T: ClassType    {
    method.Invoke((T)this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure how to restrict template types for methods!

Comment: While you're here, any idea how to specify multiple possible classes that all derive from `class`? Multiple classes listed after `where T:` seems to break it.

Comment: @KthProg separate them with comma class, new

Comment: It constrains the generic to a class we know can be converted to `T`, which removes the error. In this case I think we mean class to be the `*ClassType*` specified above. Also new does not work for what I was asking for. I edited it to match what I thought the user meant.

Comment: well it doesn't on me. cause limiting `T` to be a `class` type is not enough to make that cast valid. can you please show your full code which works if there is any?

Comment: @Selman22 I edited the post to match what I'd assumed it meant. I thought the user was using `class` as a placeholder for my class' type.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I had to wait a certain amount of time before I was allowed to.

Comment: @KthProg there is another constraint which limits type parameter to be a reference type. which is what was written in this answer.. now it's completely changed though...

Comment: I went in and fixed it. The initial answer may have been wrong. Oh well.